# Draw inverted triangle

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm building a custom TabBar in Flutter and i'm trying to draw an inverted triangle (as indicators) using specific Paths below the label. And to make the indicator move on tab selected.

Here's what i have so far

```
class TriangleTabIndicator extends Decoration {
  final BoxPainter _painter;

  TriangleTabIndicator({@required Color color, @required double radius})
      : _painter = DrawTriangle(color);

  @override
  BoxPainter createBoxPainter([onChanged]) => _painter;
}

class DrawTriangle extends BoxPainter {
  Paint _paint;

  DrawTriangle(Color color) {
    _paint = Paint()
      ..color = color
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Offset offset, ImageConfiguration cfg) {
    final Offset triangleOffset =
        offset + Offset(cfg.size.width / 2, cfg.size.height - 10);
    var path = Path();

    path.moveTo(triangleOffset.dx, triangleOffset.dy);
    path.lineTo(triangleOffset.dx + 10, triangleOffset.dy + 10);
    path.lineTo(triangleOffset.dx - 10, triangleOffset.dy + 10);

    path.close();
    canvas.drawPath(path, _paint);
  }
}
```

The above spits out an isosceles triangle. Now i need to invert this triangle.

Here's the TabBar widget

```
TabBar(
   controller: _tabController,
   indicator: TriangleTabIndicator(color: Colors.white, radius: null),
   isScrollable: true,
   indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
   labelPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 10.0),
   tabs: <Widget>[],
),
```

Comment: @pskink It worked; but it's not really what i needed. Though I've gotten an answer. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make the triangle point down...

change your `paint` method to this code:

```
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Offset offset, ImageConfiguration cfg) {
    final Offset triangleOffset = offset + Offset(cfg.size.width / 2, cfg.size.height);
    var path = Path();

    path.moveTo(triangleOffset.dx, triangleOffset.dy);
    path.lineTo(triangleOffset.dx + 10, triangleOffset.dy - 10);
    path.lineTo(triangleOffset.dx - 10, triangleOffset.dy - 10);
    path.close();

    canvas.drawPath(path, _paint);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. I should have thought of subtracting

Comment: how to port this code https://dartpad.dartlang.org/88072ef71ac41fa4a75f7bd3d2dffe72? ? trying port this traingle to line with edges like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63497345/how-to-draw-the-line-with-sharp-ends-gradient-line-in-flutter using your solution