# How to draw the line with sharp ends /gradient line/ in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Using stroke method, how to create gradient line with sharp end in flutter? I want to draw the line as below in flutter.

[image]

Comment: stroke method? what "stroke" method do you mean?

Comment: I thought when drawing object in flutter, we gotta do with stroke in custom paint. But it was different than I thought. I should have think about Path(), especially  path.quadraticBezierTo() function. @sleepingkit did good job on it.

Comment: not really,, `CustomPainter` is not a best thing for that, instead extend `Decoration` class so that it can be used for example in `Container` or `AnimatedContainer`  classes directly, for example see `CornerDecorationTest` here: https://gist.github.com/pskink/da43c327b75eec05d903fa1b4d0c4d3e

Answer (score 7):

Use CustomPainter to draw:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(Example());

class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExampleState createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            body: Center(
      child: CustomPaint(
        size: Size(200, 5),
        painter: CurvePainter(),
      ),
    )));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }
}

class CurvePainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var paint = Paint();
    paint.color = Colors.black;
    paint.style = PaintingStyle.fill; // Change this to fill

    var path = Path();

    path.moveTo(0, 0);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width / 2, size.height / 2, size.width, 0);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width / 2, -size.height / 2, 0, 0);

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: great solution, but I failed use it using offset value, how to tune this code for tabs using offset and decorator for custom tabs ? working link for traingle https://dartpad.dev/8258aac89df5c1eb979a68ae49355097  I'm failed to port your code, any help?

Answer (score 1):

modified sleepingkit answer:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PointedLinePainter extends CustomPainter {
  final double width;

  PointedLinePainter(this.width);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var paint = Paint();
    paint.color = Colors.white;
    paint.style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    var path = Path();

    path.moveTo(0, 0);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(width / 3, 0.5, width, 0);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(width / 3, -0.5, 0, 0);

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

somewhere in code:

```
Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: 2,
      child: CustomPaint(
        painter:
            PointedLinePainter(width - 2 * horizontalPointedLineMargin),
      ),
    )
```

[image]

Comment: using Boxpainter we can't use directly use drawPath ? why it's not refreshing every time I click on the tab ? https://dartpad.dartlang.org/88072ef71ac41fa4a75f7bd3d2dffe72?

Comment: how to port this using offset value while using it in Tabs like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61199129/draw-inverted-triangle

Answer (score 0):

Can't see your picture.You can use the CustomPaint widget to draw lines, define a class that extends CustomPainter, and use the canvas.drawLine() method.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**Divider class**

A thin horizontal line, with padding on either side.

In the material design language, this represents a divider. Dividers can be used in lists, Drawers, and elsewhere to separate content.

To create a divider between ListTile items, consider using ListTile.divideTiles, which is optimized for this case.

The box's total height is controlled by height. The appropriate padding is automatically computed from the height.

```
    [![// Flutter code sample for Divider

// This sample shows how to display a Divider between an orange and blue box
// inside a column. The Divider is 20 logical pixels in height and contains a
// vertically centered black line that is 5 logical pixels thick. The black
// line is indented by 20 logical pixels.
//
// !\[\](https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/material/divider.png)

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

/// This Widget is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: MyStatelessWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// This is the stateless widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  MyStatelessWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>\[
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.amber,
              child: const Center(
                child: Text('Above'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const Divider(
            color: Colors.black,
            height: 20,
            thickness: 5,
            indent: 20,
            endIndent: 0,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: const Center(
                child: Text('Below'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        \],
      ),
    );
  }
}]
```

Here info how to change style [enter link description here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Divider-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child:  SizedBox(
              height: 3,
              child: Container(
                decoration:  BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                        colors: [Colors.white, Colors.black],
                        begin: Alignment.centerRight,
                        end: Alignment.centerLeft
                    )
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
         
          Expanded(
            child:  SizedBox(
              height: 3,
              child: Container(
                decoration:  BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                        colors: [Colors.white, Colors.black],
                        begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        end: Alignment.centerRight
                    )
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).