# How to create a tiny edge divider in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How to create a tiny edge horizontal line as the below image

[image: example]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63497345/how-to-draw-the-line-with-sharp-ends-gradient-line-in-flutter

check this answer to draw a line, Starts icons can be placed using a stack

Comment: @javeedishaq thanks a lot this one solved my problem :D

Answer (score 1):

The simple method is to divide a line into two main parts and draw a gradient in these two parts and place the star icon in the middle of this line.

```
Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child:  SizedBox(
              height: 3,
              child: Container(
                decoration:  BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                        colors: [Colors.white, Colors.black],
                        begin: Alignment.centerRight,
                        end: Alignment.centerLeft
                    )
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Icon(Icons.star, size: 15,),
                Icon(Icons.star, size: 30,),
                Icon(Icons.star, size: 15,),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child:  SizedBox(
              height: 3,
              child: Container(
                decoration:  BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                        colors: [Colors.white, Colors.black],
                        begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        end: Alignment.centerRight
                    )
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

Divider has a height property.  Not sure it'd let you draw the stars though.  https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Divider-class.html

Comment: $RandalSchwartz thanks for your help, I know this property this gives the height of the whole divider not the edge